# Sublime Text - Remove plugin's keymap shortcuts

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext, sublimetext3, keymapping, sublime-text-plugin

In ST3, I want to keep the default key-map for super+alt+v, which is the paste history menu.

However, a plugin that I would like to use overrides those keys in it's default keymap. Can I remove the plugin's shortcut for super+alt+v or the keymap entirely?

---

This is what I want to keep (from the 'Default (OSX).sublime-keymap')

{ "keys": ["super+option+v"], "command": "paste_from_history" }

The is the perpetrator:

{ "keys": ["super+alt+v"], "command": "text_pastry_insert_text", "args": { "clipboard": true, "separator": "\n" } },

Comment: Isn't there anything in the plugin's preferences ? What's the plugin's name ? You just made me discover a new shortcut in ST3 =)

Comment: The plugin is [Text Pastry](https://github.com/duydao/Text-Pastry). I don't see anything in the settings menu. Think itll take modifying or overwriting the keymap.

Comment: Hey, I just spotted this on their Readme : https://github.com/duydao/Text-Pastry#key-bindings "As always, you can use your user keycap file to setup your own key bindings." ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out the Plugin's User settings will override the Plugin's Default.

So I copied { "keys": ["super+option+v"], "command": "paste_from_history" } from the original Default Sublime keymap into Text Pastry/User keymap and it's back. Thanks @Martin for talking it out with me.

Comment: Seems that it may be necessary to restart Sublime before the new shortcut takes effect (under some circumstances?)

Comment: Concretely, this means: Click `Preferences` -> `Key bindings`, and put the desired keybinding in on the user side. It will take precedence over the plugin's key binding.